# How can open an .sh file in the browser displaying html content?

Tags: html, bash, browser, hybrid

I have a bash script that is used to download software without installation

```
curl get.foo.com | bash
```

however opening `get.foo.com` in the browser does not display nice html content.

Is it possible to create a hybrid bash script that renders as almost valid HTML in a browser?

Comment: You could do something nicer by feeding a different document back based on the user agent. If it's curl, give it a script. If it's a browser, give it a document.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your bash script the following way

```
#!/bin/bash
#<html><head><!--

# Your Bash script goes here

<<HTML_CONTENT 
-->
<body style="background-color:white; margin-top:-1em">
    <!-- Your HTML code goes here -->
<!--
HTML_CONTENT
# --></body></html>
```

This works at least under Chrome 26 and Firefox 20 leaving only the first shebang line visible to the browser user.
However with some CSS styling it is possible to hide that.

Comment: there is still some garbage displayed, and bash complains about the `<<EOF ]]>` line…